# Sorting a gridview using a datatable, and datasource that is an ArrayList

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatable, postback

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

This article deals with creating a datatable first, then creating a gridview from it, to aid in sorting. My predicament is slightly different.

I have a Gridview, that on Page_Load, I set the datasource to an ArrayList, and bind.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.GridView1.DataSource = RequestManager.Instance.GetAllRequests();
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to sort this GridView, so on the aspx page, I set AllowSorting="true", and OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting". So far, so good. I have the SortExpressions set in the BoundFields, and when I click on it, I know the _Sorting event is triggered.

Now, since this is a postback operation, I cannot simply cast the datasource of the gridview to a DataTable to sort. Saving to ViewState is an option, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I would like to use the simple solution on [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2008/04/15/manually-sorting-and-paging-gridview-without-using-datasource-control.aspx), except for the DataTable not being available to me. Thanks for looking.

Comment: The `DataSource` is null on postbacks anyway. Why do you still use an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<T>`, are you on .NET 1.1? You should pass the `SortExpression` to `GetAllRequests`. Then you can apply the sort there(f.e. via Linq's `OrderBy` or sql).

Comment: I'm managing an external project, and am not in a position to change the ArrayList to List<T>. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to target .NET v3.5, I recommend using Linq. In your _Sorting event handler, get the array list you did in the Page_Load and rebind it.

For example, if the type contained in the array list are `MyType` instances that have properties named Default and SomeField:

```
protected void Grid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
  Func<MyType, object> keySelector;
  if(e.SortExpresion == "SomeField")
  {
    keySelector = dataItem => dataItem.SomeField;
  }
  else
  {
    keySelector = dataItem => dataItem.Default;
  }
  ArrayList dataItems = RequestManager.Instance.GetAllRequests();
  this.GridView1.DataSource = dataItems.OfType<MyType>().OrderBy(keySelector);
  this.GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

That will get you started, then later inspect the sort expression to see if it ends with ASC or DESC and conditionally call `.OrderByDescending(keySelector)`.

Finally, I don't recommend stashing the list in ViewState, as the `ObjectStateFormatter` is only optimized for a handful of types. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.objectstateformatter.aspx

Maybe consider ASP.NET cache instead.